# Object 'extends' Class Passing Its Own Field/Method?

Tags: scala

Given the following class:

```
scala> class Foo(x: Int) {}
defined class Foo
```

Is it possible for me to `extend` **Foo** from an `object` using its field/method?

```
scala> object Bar extends Foo(f) { 
     |   lazy val f = 100
     | }
<console>:8: error: not found: value f
       object Bar extends Foo(f) { 
                              ^
```

Comment: Yeah, if you can live with `f` not being lazy: `object Bar extends { val f = 100 } with Foo(f)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, yes this is possible, thanks to Scala's early initialization syntax:

```
object Bar extends {
  val f = 100
} with Foo(f)
```

This won't work if `f` is lazy, but given that `Foo`'s constructor is by-value that doesn't make any real difference here, anyway.